# Any nice configuration driven form projects out there?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, dynamic, configuration

I'm looking to create a generic form application, each form definition and form input being defined by configuration downloaded from a database. So configuration will include things like input type, validation, default value, etc. The form being built-up dynamically at run-time on request.

It must be a fairly common problem that's been solved many times? Anyone know of any projects out there I can take inspiration / some best practices from? Or even re-use as-is?

The end app I'm developing will be a [mobile Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development) based app, so will be developed in javascript and preferably suck in the configuration via json. Though I'm keen to look at non javascript / json apps if some inspiration can taken away e.g. C#, xml configuration, etc.

Comment: I started to build one years ago. You're welcome to scrape it: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/jameslab/JSONForm/

Comment: Thanks Diodeus - looks like a good start! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What I am about to suggest is *not* an out-of-the-box solution for you. Rather, it is something that might provide you with inspiration for (a subset of) the problem that you want to address.

Visit [www.config4star.org](http://www.config4star.org/) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer of that project) and scroll down to the "Download the manuals" section of the web page. Skim read Chapters 2 and 3 of the "Getting Started Guide" to get an understanding of the configuration syntax and API. Then, read Section 5.2 ("Validation Checks for Parameters") of the "Practical Usage Guide".

That section explains how to use a configuration file to specify validation checks for data. The example given in the text validates the values of parameters passed to an operation rather than values in a web form. So it is not quite what you are looking for, but some of the principles discussed in the text might provide you with inspiration.